# Binding domain name to Apache Virtual host on VPS

Tags: apache-httpd, dns, domain

recently company I work for has rented VPS.

Now i need to have multiple websites hosted on this VPS, that is not a problem, I'v set up virtual hosts, databses, etc.
Now i wanted to test it, see if I could access website on the VPS by domain name (**bennyben.cz**).
Domain is registered at different registrar, I've pointed DNS A record to IP address of VPS (**193.105.159.72**) and it works fine (displays apache default site), but i need to route this domain name (bennyben.cz) to virtual host on the VPS (bennyben.cz.vhost).

After some googling, I thought that I needed to add new primary DNS zone record (i have ISPConfig installed on VPS) and direct it to virtual host, so i binded the virtual host to local IP address (192.168.1.1) and set A record on VPS to this address, but if i type the domain name, it still serves the default site.

So my question is, what do i need to host multiple websites with domain names on one VPS (only one WAN IP address available), i did a lot of googling, messed around with BIND, but nothing seems to work.

System details

```
Ubuntu 13.04
ISPConfig
1 WAN IP address
```

P.S. I'm sure this is pretty basic stuff, but I work there as a programmer, so servers aren't my specialization, but, unfortunately we currently do not have anybody who could take care of the VPS, so it has fallen to me.

```
Listen 80
```

is present in /etc/apache2/ports.conf

**The vhosts config files are generated for me by ISPconfig*

Configuration files:
**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-bennyben.cz.vhost**

```
<Directory /var/www/bennyben.cz>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/bennyben.cz/web

    ServerName bennyben.cz
    ServerAlias www.bennyben.cz
    ServerAdmin webmaster@bennyben.cz

    ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/bennyben.cz/error.log

    Alias /error/ "/var/www/bennyben.cz/web/error/"
    ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
    ErrorDocument 405 /error/405.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
    ErrorDocument 502 /error/502.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    </IfModule>

    <Directory /var/www/bennyben.cz/web>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client4/web5/web>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>




    # suexec enabled
    <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup web5 client4
    </IfModule>
    # Clear PHP settings of this website
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
            SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    # php as fast-cgi enabled
# For config options see: http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
            FcgidIdleTimeout 300
            FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
            # FcgidMaxProcesses 1000
            FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 5000
            FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
            FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 100
            FcgidConnectTimeout 3
            FcgidIOTimeout 360
            FcgidBusyTimeout 300
            FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
    </IfModule>
    <Directory /var/www/bennyben.cz/web>
            AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php3 .php4 .php5
            FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web5/.php-fcgi-starter .php
            Options +ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client4/web5/web>
            AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php3 .php4 .php5
            FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web5/.php-fcgi-starter .php
            Options +ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>


    # add support for apache mpm_itk
    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId web5 client4
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Do not execute PHP files in webdav directory
        <Directory /var/www/clients/client4/web5/webdav>
            <ifModule mod_security2.c>
                SecRuleRemoveById 960015
                SecRuleRemoveById 960032
            </ifModule>
            <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
                SetHandler None
            </FilesMatch>
        </Directory>
        DavLockDB /var/www/clients/client4/web5/tmp/DavLock
        # DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTS!
        # IF YOU REMOVE THEM, WEBDAV WILL NOT WORK ANYMORE!
  # WEBDAV BEGIN
        # WEBDAV END
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apach2/sites-available/bennyben.cz.vhost**

```
<Directory /var/www/bennyben.cz>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/bennyben.cz/web

    ServerName bennyben.cz
    ServerAlias www.bennyben.cz
    ServerAdmin webmaster@bennyben.cz

    ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/bennyben.cz/error.log

    Alias /error/ "/var/www/bennyben.cz/web/error/"
    ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
    ErrorDocument 405 /error/405.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
    ErrorDocument 502 /error/502.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    </IfModule>

    <Directory /var/www/bennyben.cz/web>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client4/web5/web>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>




    # suexec enabled
    <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup web5 client4
    </IfModule>
    # Clear PHP settings of this website
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
            SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    # php as fast-cgi enabled
# For config options see: http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
            FcgidIdleTimeout 300
            FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
            # FcgidMaxProcesses 1000
            FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 5000
            FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
            FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 100
            FcgidConnectTimeout 3
            FcgidIOTimeout 360
            FcgidBusyTimeout 300
            FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
    </IfModule>
    <Directory /var/www/bennyben.cz/web>
            AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php3 .php4 .php5
            FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web5/.php-fcgi-starter .php
            Options +ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client4/web5/web>
            AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php3 .php4 .php5
            FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web5/.php-fcgi-starter .php
            Options +ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>


    # add support for apache mpm_itk
    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId web5 client4
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Do not execute PHP files in webdav directory
        <Directory /var/www/clients/client4/web5/webdav>
            <ifModule mod_security2.c>
                SecRuleRemoveById 960015
                SecRuleRemoveById 960032
            </ifModule>
            <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
                SetHandler None
            </FilesMatch>
        </Directory>
        DavLockDB /var/www/clients/client4/web5/tmp/DavLock
        # DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTS!
        # IF YOU REMOVE THEM, WEBDAV WILL NOT WORK ANYMORE!
  # WEBDAV BEGIN
        # WEBDAV END
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If any of the existing answers solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a formatted comment rather than an answer: is Virtual Hosting configured in your web-server? I.e. (assuming the web-server is apache and you have root access), you should have an entry in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` (which is usually a symlink to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/bennyben`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bennyben.cz.vhost
    DocumentRoot /home/bennyben/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

and also `Listen 80` should be there, if it's not in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`.

Could you supply your configs?

If anything is not working as expected, don't hesitate to look into `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply

My virtual hosts are correctly set up (http://193.105.159.72/bennyben.cz/) this works.

Unfortunately, i cannot provide configuration files because the comments windows says it is too long, should i post it into answer window? Sorry for my ignorance, this is my first question.

Thanks

Comment: @user183162 No problem. Just edit your question and add the new information.

To format data as a verbatim file excerpt (like my `<VirtualHost>...`), leave an empty line and then start each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: I've edited my original question, do you need anything else?

Comment: Thanks. (Besides, I believe `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-bennyben.cz.vhost` is just a symlink for `/etc/apach2/sites-available/bennyben.cz.vhost`, so it's just a duplication. Read permissions to your .vhost files are, probably, ok... And .vhost configs seem reasonable to me.

Comment: Hey, but with these settings you are not serving any `index.html`, right? So, when you just type `http://bennyben.cz` in the address line, apache shouldn't serve anything (it would've served `index.html`, but it doesn't exist in your `var/www/bennyben.cz/web`). I've typed in `http://bennyben.cz/index.html` and got Internal Server Error. So everything seems ok. Try adding a static html page, e.g. "index.html" to your `/var/www/bennyben.cz/web` and check if it gets served. `http://bennyben.cz/index.php` gave me internal server error, too. So, see the error log.

Comment: I have created directory
    var/www/bennyben.cz/web and uploaded index.html file, still 500 error, but in error log is this: 
    [Fri Jul 26 16:53:11 2013] [crit] [client 83.208.254.144] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /

I will do some googling and leave a comment if I find something interesting

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and also, I've learned a little about how to post on SO. Many thanks and have a nice day :)

Comment: @user183162 No worries, glad it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Per the OP's original edit to the question:

Got it working, all I had to do was add

```
Satisfy any
```

to

```
Directory
```

statement. e.g:

```
<Directory /var/www/bennyben.cz/web>
    Satisfy any
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```